# Zooming and panning of two plotspaces in CorePlot

Tags: ios, core-plot

So I have two plotspaces and a plot on each. One is a scatter plot, the other is a bar chart plot.

Currently, I have zooming turned on (Y axis disabled) and a pan guesture recogniser for the panning.

Here is my code for the PlotSpace delegate methods.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PlotSpace Delegates

- (CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)proposedDisplacementVector{
    return CGPointMake(0, 0);

}

- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint {
    return YES;
}

- (CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate {
    if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateX) {
        [self checkIfCluster];
        return [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:newRange.location length:newRange.length];

    } else {
        if ([space.identifier  isEqual: @"barplotspace"]) {
            return [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(10)]; //Look out for other one.

        }
            return [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([self getMaxValue] * 1.25)]; //Look out for other one.

    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space didChangePlotRangeForCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    [self updateStats];
}

-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender{

    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];

    CPTXYPlotSpace *space = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)[self.hostView.hostedGraph defaultPlotSpace];
    CGFloat movementDistance = space.xRange.lengthDouble / self.hostView.frame.size.width;
    if (translation.x > 0) {
        space.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(space.xRange.locationDouble - movementDistance * 30) length:space.xRange.length];

    } else {
        space.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(space.xRange.locationDouble + movementDistance * 30) length:space.xRange.length];

    }

}
```

However, I have also set both plotspaces' delegates at time of creation to self (where these methods are defined). `willChangePlotRangeTo` is being called from the bar plotspace. Not the `willDisplaceBy` or the `shouldScaleBy`... which is odd. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd forgotten to turn on allows user interaction on BOTH plotspaces.

Answer (score 0):

The `-plotSpace:willDisplaceBy:` delegate method is only called from the `-pointingDeviceDraggedEvent:atPoint:` method when panning with the built-in event handling.

The `-plotSpace:shouldScaleBy:aboutPoint:` delegate method is only called from `-scaleBy:aboutPoint:` method. The built-in pinch gesture recognizer uses this method to scale the plot space in response to the gesture.